# selenium unable to locate element - i've tried find by name, find by classname, find by xpath, but all return unable to locate element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm stuck on a very simple part of a selenium script that should take me 5 seconds.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="000-000-0000" name="phoneNumber" 
class="ew6td2426 css-1p641ex ejlqu6x14" value="">
```

there are multiple elements with the name phoneNumber, but i just want to grab the first one, which is here.

```
when i grab the xpath, it gives me this


//*[@id="js-global-container"]/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/input


placing it into the script as this

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='js-global- 
container']/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/input")
```

but again, the script says it cannot find the method.

does anyone have an easy fix for this? I cant figure this out and its driving me insane

Answer (score 0):

Try switching frames:

```py
driver.switch_to.frame('find your frame element here with driver.find')
```

For switching back:

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Where did you find the `frame`?

Comment: just search through html source of the page

Comment: Which page/webpage?

Comment: I don't know the page you are trying to suse selenium on it, but your problem seems to be related to frames,
just search frame through the page source.

Comment: I mean to ask, why blaming the frames? Why not blaming the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance i.e. the _driver_ or blaming the _Browsing Context_ i.e. _Chrome_?